# Same model performs very diferent in Keras and Flux

Tags: machine-learning, keras, julia, flux.jl

In a class I'm taking, the professor gave us two datasets, one of 301 late-type galaxies and the other one of 301 early-type galaxies, and we build a model in Keras so it can differentiate them:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(128,128,3))

x = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size= (3,3), strides = (1,1), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),padding = 'same')(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size= (3,3), strides = (1,1), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),padding = 'same')(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size= (3,3), strides = (1,1), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),padding = 'same')(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(x)
out = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs = input_img, outputs = out)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 20)
```

Since I like Julia more than Python, I tried to build the same model in Flux.jl and according to what I read in the Flux Docs this is what the Flux model looks like:

```
model2 = Chain(            
    Conv((3, 3), 3 => 16, relu, pad=SamePad(), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2), pad=SamePad()),
    Conv((3, 3), 16 => 32, relu, pad=SamePad(), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2), pad=SamePad()),
    Conv((3, 3), 32 => 64, relu, pad=SamePad(), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2), pad=SamePad()),
    Flux.flatten,
    Dense(16384 => 32, relu),
    Dense(32 => 16, relu),

    Dense(16 => 1),
    sigmoid
)
```

But when I train the models in what I think are the same conditions, I get very different results. In Keras the final lost after 20 Epochs is `loss: 0.0267` and in Flux after 30 Epochs the loss is `0.4082335f0`, so I don't know where this difference in loss could come from since I'm using the same batch size in both models and the data treatment is the same (I think).
Python:

```
X1 = np.load('/home/luis/Descargas/cosmo-late.npy')
X2 = np.load('/home/luis/Descargas/cosmo-early.npy')
X = np.concatenate((X1,X2), axis = 0).astype(np.float32)/256.0
Y = np.zeros(X.shape[0])
Y[0:len(X1)] = 1
rand_ind = np.arange(0,X.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(rand_ind)
X = X[rand_ind]
Y = Y[rand_ind]
X_train = X[50:]
Y_train = Y[50:]
X_test = X[0:50]
Y_test = Y[0:50]
```

Julia:

```
X1 = npzread("./Descargas/cosmo-late.npy")
X2 = npzread("./Descargas/cosmo-early.npy")
X = cat(X1,X2,dims=1)
X = Float32.(X)./256
Y = zeros(1,size(X)[1])
Y[1,1:length(X1[:,1,1,1])] .= 1
ind = collect(1:length(Y[1,:]))
shuffle!(ind)
X = X[ind,:,:,:]
Y = Y[:,ind]
X_train = X[51:length(X[:,1,1,1]),:,:,:]
Y_train = Y[:,51:length(Y)]
X_test = X[1:50,:,:,:]
Y_test = Y[:,1:50]
X_train = permutedims(X_train, (2, 3, 4, 1))
X_test = permutedims(X_test, (2, 3, 4, 1))
```

And the training in Julia goes:

```
train_set = Flux.DataLoader((X_train, Y_train), batchsize=32)
loss(x, y) = Flux.logitbinarycrossentropy(x, y)
opt = Flux.setup(Adam(), model2)
loss_history = Float32[]

for epoch = 1:30
    Flux.train!(model2, train_set, opt) do m,x,y
        err = loss(m(x), y)
        ChainRules.ignore_derivatives() do
            push!(loss_history, err)
        end
        return err
    end
end
```

Can anyone pls help me, I can't figure it out.

Comment: The first model has a dropout between the final dense layers. Also the default parameters for used Adam optimizers might be different

Comment: Oops, I added the dropout after running the model the first time and I forgot to remove it, but even without it the loss in keras is practically the same, and I checked the default parameters for Adam in keras and Flux and are the same except for one, but I also tested defining the exact same parameters manually in both models and still don't fix the problem

Comment: I think if you use `logitbinarycrossentropy` you shouldn't have `sigmoid` in the last layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment about skipping `sigmoid` when using `logitbinarycrossentropy`, I had a quick go at testing this for some scrap data, and with your current implementation I also ended up at 0.5 ish loss, while after removing the `sigmoid` I reached much lower values.

You can also choose to keep the `sigmoid` and use `binarycrossentropy` instead, though it seems that is not as numerically stable so it is better to do it with `logitbinarycrossentropy`.

Comment: Omg that's it! Thank you so much! You save my sanity, just one last question, the activation function on the last layer is sigmoid in the keras model, but then why is it not needed in the Flux model? I checked the documentation and apparently the logitbinarycrossentropy have a sigmoid function applying on the input data but then that means that there's two function applying on the output that on the model? (The default function of the dense layer and the sigmoid of the loss function?).

Comment: So if you want to recreate the keras model you would have the `sigmoid` and switch to using `binarycrossentropy`. Using `logitbinarycrossentropy` is more numerically stable because it directly calculates entropy on the logits (before sigmoid) and I guess keeping more precision by doing so.

So what you had in your case was basically equivalent to two sigmoid activations in the keras model, which I guess would not work well either.

Answer (score 1):

after viewing your code, I don't think this model weight could be update in julia,

the model should be contained in your loss code.
here is an example for how to set your loss func.

```
loss3(model, x, y) = norm(model(x) .- y)        # the model is the first argument
```

PS. and there is also a simple syntax of Flux train:

```
train!(loss, model, data, opt_state)
```

hope these help, and above code from the help of `?Flux.train!` in julia.